# Visual Studio's Access Modifier drop down option is disabled for resource file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resx, access-modifiers

Not sure why Access Modifier drop down is disabled for a Resource file.

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9157/accessmodifier.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/9157/accessmodifier.png)

Here are file properties:

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3930/resxprop.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3930/resxprop.png)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If possible, change your Custom Tool back to the default "ResXFileCodeGenerator".

I tried changing a default web app project to use "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator" and it caused the Access Modifier drop down to disable.

Comment: yeah that does it. you can also set custom tool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator. http://guysmithferrier.com/post/2008/06/Public-Strongly-Typed-Resources-With-PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.aspx

Comment: or just make it empty

Answer (score 15):

1. Right click on your file resource, choose **Properties** (`Alt+Enter`)
2. Change Build Action to **Embedded Resource**
3. Change Custom Tool to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`

Now it works.

Comment: You might also need to change the "Custom Tool Namespace" in the properties window to Resources, otherwise the paths to the strings change when changing the tool

Comment: Of all the various suggestions on the internet, this is the only one I've found that works!  The magic ingredient is changing the namespace. ^^^^