# Get DisplayName from resource file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have culture specific resource files in App_GlobalResources folder. Now I need to read value of the DisplayName attribute from this resource files. I am using:

```
[Display(Name = "MerchantName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string Merchant { get; set; }
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'Resources.Resource' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'MerchantName'.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 21):

In my case I had to change the Access modifier of my resource from Internal to Public.

[image: Public_vs_Internal]

By default all Resources are created as Internal.

Comment: This worked for me too. I saw the 'internal' in the code, but didn't know where to change it. I was about to waste a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: It's works. before it, I change modifier of resource manually.

Comment: In my case (ASP.Net MVC VS 2019), the access modifier dropdown was disabled. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790016/199745 fixed the disabled dropdown issue.After the dropdown was enabled, the access modifier was automatically set to public.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Your resource file access modifier should be declared as `public`;
2. It contains a key `MerchantName`

   ```
   [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Name = "MerchantName")]
   public string MerchantName{ get; set; }
   ```

For more information, refer http://www.dotnetlibrary.com/Articles/GetArticles?articleId=20

Comment: And if both conditions are satisfied but it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Azimuth have you solved that yet? I'm stuck and there is no workaround on the internet.