# No Custom Tool in resx file properties

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resx, access-modifiers

I want to change the access modifier of my *.resx file to public. However, the Access Modifier drop down option is disabled.

I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142782/visual-studios-access-modifier-drop-down-option-is-disabled-for-resource-file), where it says to change the file's Custom Tool back to the default "ResXFileCodeGenerator". But, in my file properties, there isn't a field for Custom Tool:
[image: resx file properties: file name and file path]

How do I get the Custom Tool property?

Comment: Do you see the custom tool for other file types? I get it for almost every type.

Comment: @Remy - No, I don't get it for any file type.

Comment: What if you setup a new project? Just to try. You should have those settings for all filetypes.

Comment: @Remy I seem to have found the problem - what I have is a website project, and not a web application project...