# Visual Studio 2015, can't change access modifier of new resources files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, resx

I'm trying to create new resources files in VS2015. I created them fine, but when I try to change the "Access Modifier", the dropdown is disabled...

Any ideas?

I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET5). The project is a Class Library, but I have tested in Web Project with same results.

Thanks!!

[image]

**Edit: Added Properties window**
[image]

Comment: Open designer file (Resource.Designer.resx) on Notepad++ and change the internal/private modifier (from all property, constructor and class).

Comment: @chemitaxis, follow the instructions in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314146/visual-studio-2015-cant-change-access-modifier-of-new-resources-files/39441597#39441597)

Answer (score 14):

Can you check the property of your file and verify if Custom Tool is ResXFileCodeGenerator ? If it's GlobalResourceProxyGenerator, the dropdown will be disabled.

Comment: Go directly on Solution explorer and right click on your file to get Properties. If you just open the window Properties It won't show anything :( CustomTool is in the "Advanced" category, just after Copy To Output Directory.

Comment: Hi @arya404 I have updated my question... like you see, I don't have the option to change anything... I have tested with a clean new project with the same result...

Comment: I have tested it in a new computer with new installation of VS, but it's not working...

Comment: Can't you tell me what is the type of your project "....Resources" ? And Under your *.resx file, do you have the Designer file ?

Comment: I have read about it... it's like VS2015 with ASP.NET 5 projects has changed how works with resources... But, for your question... it's a class library

Comment: I've got the same issue :(

Comment: Same issue! I can able to access properties of .resx and change access modifier and check the tool that is active in older version of VS but not in VS 2015

Comment: Did anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: same thing here :I

Comment: @Simon and others, Yes, follow the instructions in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314146/visual-studio-2015-cant-change-access-modifier-of-new-resources-files/39441597#39441597)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but I found this easy solution [*Visual Studio's Access Modifier drop down option is disabled for resource file*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790016/109702)

To summarize:

> 1. Right click on your file resource, choose Properties (Alt+Enter)
> 2. Change Build Action to Embedded Resource
> 3. Change Custom Tool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

Comment: How do you change this? This is how my property pages looks like for my .resx file: http://imgur.com/0DYC6d9

Comment: I just rightclicked on my resource file from solution explorer panel. I had much different view then you got here.

Comment: Is your project an asp core project?

Comment: It's ASP.NET MVC project.

Answer (score 3):

**A) In *Asp.net Core* projects**

This problem is a [known bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/339) in `Asp.net Core` projects and access modifier is on `public` by default and you can not change it. It will be solved by asp.net core team next updates **but** if you need `internal` access modifier you can use my temporary solution:

1. **Add** your all items by the resource designer in your `Resource.resx` and **save** it
2. In the solution explorer expand the `Resource.resx` tree and **open `Resource.Designer.cs`**
3. **Replace** all `public` strings in it with `internal` and **save** it

> **Note:** every time you save the `Resource.resx` file you should do the **step 3** again.

Finally you should have a `Resource.Designer.cs` file with access modifiers like this:
[image]

*Also check the `namespace` in `Resource.Designer.cs` file. it should be a appropriate `namespace`. Sync with your project `namespace`.*

---

**B) In *Normal Asp.net* projects**

> **If** you have not `CustomTool` property in the `Properties panel` for your resource (`.resx`) file to change it to
>   `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and solve the problem
>
> **Then** you should change some settings in your project (`.csproj`) file manually. It's so easy, just follow my instructions:

1. Right click on your project in `solution explorer` and select **Unload Project**
2. Right click again on it and select **Edit .....csproj**
3. In the opened `.csproj` file, **find** the `.resx` string, you will see a block of settings there. That is something like bellow codes.
4. **Change** it to something like the following code (include 
   **`PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`**):

.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="MyResourceFile.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>

      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator> <!--important line-->

      <LastGenOutput>MyResourceFile.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

5. **Save** the edited `.csproj` file
6. Right click again on your project in the `solution explorer` and select **Reload project**
7. Now **open** your `.resx` file and enjoy ;)

> **Note:** use your resource file name instead of `MyResourceFile`

Comment: But what if there is no `.csproj` file - just a `.xproj` file (note question's the tags)?

Comment: @Tubbe, good point. I edited my answer and added a new temporary solution for this bug in `asp.net core` projects. I hope it works.

Comment: @Simon, i tested it. I created a new Core project and did the core part instruction then i built the core project. Now if i open `Resource.Designer.cs` file i see all access modifiers are `internal` in it. So what is your problem?

Comment: @RAM when I edit the access modifiers to public, I am getting MissingManifestResourceException

Comment: @Simon, i edited my answer with a pic. Default value is `public` and every time you open the `.resx` file and save it, all access modifiers in it will be changed to `public` automatically (reason is the bug) so there is no need to edit them to `public` manually. If you want public access modifier just open and save it BUT if you want `internal` you can try part `A` of my answer. I test it several times without any error. Check namespace in your `Resource.Designer.cs` file. It should has an appropriate namespace. Also read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692#1329631).

Comment: @RAM can I provide some details to you in the chat?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a similar problem.

This appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/339